# Cannot use gcloud compute ssh command in python subprocess

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a compute engine already set up, I can use ssh command in command prompt, like

```
gcloud compute ssh test-instance@cloud-engine-noapi --zone us-central1-f --command "rm -f test.txt"
```

and successfully delete the test.txt in server.

However, when I call these in python.

```
subprocess.call(['gcloud', 'compute', '--project', 'test-project','ssh', temp_instance, '--zone', zone, '--command', '"cd /home"'], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['gcloud', 'compute', '--project', 'test-project','ssh', temp_instance, '--zone', zone, '--command', '"ls -l"'], shell=True)
subprocess.call(['gcloud', 'compute', '--project', 'test-project','ssh', temp_instance, '--zone', zone, '--command', '"rm -f /home/test.txt"'], shell=True)
```

The return is always like

```
bash: /command : No such file or directory
```

and for command like `ls`

```
bash: /command : command not found
```

Is there any process I have to do first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though, probably no one has this problem... but I finally come up with a method to solve it.

As the problem only occurs when using subprocess, I bypass it by writing a (bat/sh) file to temporarily save the commands.

Like,

```
with open(os.path.join(__location__, 'gcloud_command.bat'), 'w') as bat:
            command_arr = []
            for instance in all_instances_name:
                temp_instance = user_name + "@" + instance
                temp_file_path = '/home/' + user_name + '/'
                command_arr.append('call gcloud compute ssh ' + temp_instance + ' --zone ' + zone + ' --command "cd ' + temp_file_path + '; rm -rf ' + temp_file_path + projectname.split('.')[0] + '; rm -f ' + temp_file_path + projectname.split('.')[0] + '*"\n')
                command_arr.append('call gcloud compute scp "' + fullpath_projectname + '" ' + instance + ':' + temp_file_path + '\n')
                if is_zip:
                    command_arr.append('call gcloud compute ssh ' + temp_instance + ' --zone ' + zone + ' ' + ' --command "cd ' + temp_file_path + '; unzip ' + temp_file_path + projectname + '"' + '\n')
            bat.writelines(command_arr)
```

And execute with

```
subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(__location__, 'gcloud_command.bat'))
```

Comment: Although the cli cmd can work without specifying --zone, I needed to specify it in .sh file to run as a subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is quite old but it took me some time to figure it out.
In my case helped avoiding double quotes (despite it's recommended by gcloud cli help).

Example:

```
subprocess.call(['gcloud', 'compute', f'--project={test-project}','ssh', temp_instance, f'--zone={zone}, '--command=cd /home'], shell=True)
```